# Cloud-init conf for Ununtu Server 22.04 late-commands take no effec

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, cloud-init

Using Ubuntu Server 22.04, I am attempting to create an auto-installation setup for a physical client. I want to enable root login and execute late commands. Additionally, I want the hostname to be set as "new-client-macadress" without colons. Despite trying various syntaxes, the commands do not seem to take effect. I have experimented with different configurations, but none have yielded the desired results.

```
#cloud-config

autoinstall:

  version: 1

  user-data:

    hostname: new-client

    timezone: Europe/Stockholm

    chpasswd:

      expire: false

      list:

        - root:$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0

  keyboard:

    layout: se

    toggle: null

    variant: ''

   

  late-commands:

   - sed -i "s?new-client?new-client-$(cat /target/sys/class/net/enp*/address | sed 's/\://g')?g" /target/etc/hostname /etc/hosts"

   - echo "PermitRootLogin yes" | tee -a /target/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

   - systemctl restart ssh
```

Grateful for any suggestions